# ¿Se puede hacer un "git checkout" de todos los archivos con una extensión determinada?

Tags: git

Tengo algo como lo siguiente cuando uso `git status`:

```
Su rama está actualizada con «origin/master».
Cambios para hacer commit:
  (use «git reset HEAD <archivo>...» para sacar del stage)

    modificado:    .ftpquota
    modificado:    recursos/.ftpquota
    modificado:    recursos/contenidos/archivo.Default.html
    modificado:    recursos/contenidos/archivo.PopUpView.html
    modificado:    recursos/contenidos/archivo.js
    modificado:    recursos/contenidos/archivo.php
    modificado:    recursos/contenidos/archivo2.php
    modificado:    recursos/contenidos/archivo.txt
    modificado:    recursos/contenidos/archivo3.php
    ... (muchos muchos más archivos) ....
```

Lo que quiero es descartar cambios de todos los archivos con extensión **.php**. Para ello sé que con el siguiente comando puede descartar dichos cambios:

```
$ git checkout -- ruta/archivo.ext
```

El problema viene en que son muchos archivos e ir uno por uno me lleva mucho tiempo. Se me ocurre hacer un bucle bash y uso de awk, pero imagino que debe existir otra forma para hacerlo más simple con git.

Comment: Por cierto, es conveniente evitar que se realicen tantas modificaciones en el código juntas y `checkout` pierde tus cambios (sin posibilidad de recuperarlos) así que es un riesgo. Quizás deberías ver como evitar que estos cambios globales sucedan en una primera instancia.

Comment: estaría bueno que indiques si alguna de las respuestas te sirvió http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 9):

Usando `git checkout -- *.php **/*.php` al parecer funciona.

Lo que usa es la expansión de globs de bash, de forma que el comando que git recibe en realidad es:

```
git checkout -- a.php a/b.php ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Quiza algo como esto te pueda servir

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec git checkout -- {} \;
```

**Explicación**

- find: Utilidad que recorre de manera recursiva un arbol de
  directorios dado, evaluando una expresión dada en este caso (-name
  "*.php").
- Punto (.): Representa el directorio actual dentro de la    jerarquía
  de directorios unix/Linux.
- -name: Parámetro que indica un patrón de búsqueda, utilizando el nombre del archivo.
- -exec: Llama una utilidad externa (en este caso git) y le envía uno por uno el resultado de la búsqueda (el path de cada archivo que hizo match con la expresión dada en -name) utilizando {}.
- \; : expresión que finaliza la llamada la utilidad externa.

Comment: En general conviene usar `-iname` en vez de `-name` para ignorar mayúsculas (y atrapar archivos como algo.PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Crea un archivo .gitignore con el siguiente contenido:

```
*.php
```

Con esto estarás descartando u omitiendo todos los archivos con extensión .php de tu proyecto, carpeta u repositorio.

Importante: el archivo debe llamarse exactamente `.gitignore`, incluyendo el punto.

Comment: No deseo ignorar los cambios en dichos archivos, sólo eliminar los cambios hecho en un último estado.